SharePoint 2019 - Left Navigation stuck on "Loading..."

I'm not sure what has changed, but for some reason my SharePoint 2019 website is doing this now. What I have found is it only happens when I try to access the SharePoint site from https://sharepoint.domain.com/. And then after I refresh a couple of times or clear browser cache it clears up for a little while. I also noticed that our company logo will be missing on https but on http it is fine.
but if I just go to http://sharepoint.domain.com/ it loads just fine.
The only thing about this issue was from this forum post - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/134136/left-navigation-not-loading-on-sharepoint-server-2?page=2#answers
I tried the patching recommendations that they made, but it didn't help me at all.

Could you add how you configured HTTPS?

Is your company logo referenced with a HTTP link? Because when using HTTPS it won't load 'unsafe' HTTP items. Same for your menu if it contains full URL's starting with HTTP.

Site Binding
Type: https
IP address: All Unassigned
Port: 443
Hostname: sharepoint.domain.com
Require Server Name Indication: Unchecked
Disable HTTP/2: Unchecked
Disabled OCSP Stapling: Unchecked
SSL certificate: sharepoint.domain.com
When I first try to access https://sharepoint.domain.com/ it prompts me to enter my credentials. Does this indicate that the certificate is not installed correctly by chance?
Also, every once in awhile I will get this error too after signing in:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Date: Mon, 16 Dec 2024 14:00:23 GMT
Connection: close

Did you extend the webapplication or just added HTTPS to the already present IIS website? Did you see my other comment? Are the links HTTP or HTTPS?

I did not extend the web application, only added HTTPS to present IIS website. My apologies, I thought I had responded to your other comment. All of my links when I hover over them are HTTPS. If I edit the links the address is like this for example: /SitePages/Administration.aspx

Danny, thank you so much for your help! My issue was that I needed to add the HTTPS URL to AAM. Left navigation is showing now no problem, I just had to fix URL for Logo. The only thing left I need to do I believe is to have our group policy admin add the URL to Trusted Sites so that I am no longer prompted to sign in.

Glad I could help. Maybe post the anwser and accept it so others will know what to do. Extending the webapplication is best practice. Everything is taking care of then. Like AAM.

My issue was that I needed to add the HTTPS URL to AAM. Left navigation is showing now no problem, I just had to fix URL for Logo. The only thing left I need to do I believe is to have our group policy admin add the URL to Trusted Sites so that I am no longer prompted to sign in.
Thanks again Danny for your help!
